# AVSpeechSynthesizer going crazy with textView selectedRange

Tags: objective-c, nsrange, avspeechsynthesizer

I'm trying to have the `AVSpeechSynthesizer` read the user's text selection in a `UITextView`. It works quite well when I double-tap a word but whenever I try to select more than one word, the `AVSpeechSynthesizer` starts speaking words in a weird way. Is there a way to prevent this behaviour or to retrieve the user's text selection only when they release the selecting finger ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what I do :

```
-(void) textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView{
NSRange r = textView.selectedRange;
if (!(r.length == 0)) {

    NSString *selText = [self.entryTextField2.text substringWithRange:r];
    AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:selText];
    [utterance setRate:0.5f];
    utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:self.selectedSpeakerLanguage];
    [self.synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I should have done it the Apple way from the start or at least the IOS way. Reading the selectedRange directly from textViewDidChangeSelection: is definitely not a good idea. You need to use a [UIMenuController sharedMenuController] to present a UIMenuItem that triggers the readSelection method instead.